# Android Studio classes disappear if I run or sync the project

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project but I have an awkward problem.
Everytime I try to run my application (or to sync it with gradle) three classes just disappear or to be precise they are deleted.

This is kinda awkward because there is no error message and I have to revert my project everytime.

I tried some things but the only thing I found out is that it only happens if I add one or more strings to my string.xml.

For example when I add:

```
<string name="crash_it">This is my String</string>
```

and run or sync my project it will delete a few classes (everytime the same classes). Without this line everything works perfectly.

My current string.xml looks like:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

I'd really appreciate it when some one could help me out.

//// EDIT:

Android Studio was joking around with me. It showed that my classes are in the same package but when I opened it in my filesystem all my classes which disappeard where deployed in another directoy.

I dropped them in the right directory manually and know everything works fine.

Comment: interesting. which class was deleted?

Comment: all of them are custom classes but none of the classes access the string.xml. And one of the classes is not even in use at the moment.